# angular js json response grabbing of different matches (pattern to match all type of response)

Tags: json, regex, angularjs

the response is like the following format

```
{   
    "human_man" : 
        [ 
            {"id" : "12345", "value" : "4567"}, 
            { "id" : "0000", "value" : "qwer"}
        ], 
    "human_woman" : 
        [
            {"id" : "5454", "value" : "6565"}, 
            { "id" : "7878", "value" : "884"}
        ],
    ............................................
}
```

I want to catch the response for all matches , meaning....

if I use,

response.human_man   ::: i would be catching--> `[ {"id" : "12345", "value" : "4567"}, { "id" : "0000", "value" : "qwer"}]`

if I use,

response.human_woman ::: i would be catching--> `[{"id" : "5454", "value" : "6565"}, { "id" : "7878", "value" : "884"}]`

so I want to know how to catch the response the type is

response.human_*   (it should catch response.human_man & response.human_woman)

hope you guys understood the question.. :)

fast replies would be appreciated

Comment: Where do you need to use this information, are you try-ing to iterate it with `ng-repeat`, are you trying to build a filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
var object = {
    "human_man" :
        [
            {"id" : "12345", "value" : "4567"},
            { "id" : "0000", "value" : "qwer"}
        ],
    "human_woman" :
        [
            {"id" : "5454", "value" : "6565"},
            { "id" : "7878", "value" : "884"}
        ]
};

for(var key in object) {
    if(/^human_/.test(key))
        console.log(object[key]);
}
```